# Having trouble with learning Buffer Overflows

Tags: buffer-overflow, c, stack-overflow

So I have this program in C that I'm trying to exploit which has a vulnerability in a function, namely it's using `gets`. I'm trying to overflow and change the return address so the program returns one or both of the two functions that are not called.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void half_win()
{
  printf("Well done, you got half the score\n");
}

void complete_win(){
  printf("FULL SCORE\n");
}
void vuln_func(){
  char buffer[36];
  gets(buffer);
  printf("You have entered: %s\n",buffer);
}

int main(int argc,char**argv){
  vuln_func();
}
```

So I overflow the buffer, I go to check the `esp` to calculate the offset by subtracting the address where the buffer starts from the esp's address but what's strange is that the buffer seems to overwrite the `esp`.

```
(gdb) x/24wx $esp
0xffffd0c8: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0xffffd100
0xffffd0d8: 0xffffd16c  0xffffd0f4  0x00000001  0xffffd164
0xffffd0e8: 0xf7fac000  0xf7fe574a  0xffffd160  0x00000000
0xffffd0f8: 0xf7fac000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x98862ada
0xffffd108: 0xdada4cca  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xffffd118: 0x00000040  0xf7ffd024  0x00000000  0x00000000
```

So both their addresses are the same so the offset value is 0. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. If any could give some guidance you'd be really saving me.

It's running on Ubuntu by the way.

Comment: On x86, the address given to `gets` will be in `$esp`, so `gets` will start writing at the address that `$esp` points to. `$esp` is not overwitten since it still appears to point to `0xffffd0c8` rather than e.g. `0x41414141`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a document I wrote, and will be presenting at BSides Tokyo tomorrow. Will probably help, since it looks like the same type of simple overflow.
http://sysrisk.com/files/WhyBufferOverflowsMatter.pdf

Add 8 bytes and that should overwrite EIP. Peda tools should be added to GDB to make all that offset calculation easier.

Comment: Please do not post link only answers. Include the relevant parts of the link in your answer here. If the link dies, so does this answer.